# React testing library throws "createRoot(...): Target container is not a DOM element." error when I include actions from redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-testing-library

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

above are the images of my App.js, App.test.js and error message that I am getting.

Thanks

I am not able to pass the test when I run npm test.

Comment: This happens only when uncomment "import {getAvailableAccount,getAvailableAccounts } from "./redux/App/app.actions";"

Answer (score 0):

This error message is usually caused by passing an invalid container element to the render function of React Testing Library. The render function expects a DOM element to be passed as the second argument, but it seems that in your case, an invalid element or null is being passed.

Here are a few things you can try to fix this error:

Make sure the container element is a valid DOM element:
Check that the container element you are passing to the render function is a valid DOM element. For example, if you are using document.getElementById to get the container element, make sure that the element with the specified ID actually exists in the document.

Use document.body as the container element:
If you don't have a specific container element to use, you can pass document.body as the container element to the render function. This will render the component at the end of the document body.

```
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";

test("renders component", () => {
  render(<MyComponent />, document.body);
  // ...
});
```

Use createPortal to render the component in a container element:
If you need to render the component in a specific container element, you can use the createPortal method from React to render the component in a different DOM element than the one used by the testing library.

Here's an example:

```
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import { createPortal } from "react-dom";

test("renders component in container element", () => {
  const container = document.createElement("div");
  document.body.appendChild(container);

  render(
    createPortal(<MyComponent />, container),
    { container: container }
  );
  // ...
});
```

This example creates a new DOM element and appends it to the document body. The createPortal method is then used to render the component in the new element. The render function is called with the container option to specify the container element used by the testing library.

Comment: I am still getting the same error. I think its mostly bcz of the redux actions that I am using in the App.js. If comment out those actions then everything starts working..